# I want to make a new object from array of 'n' number of objects based on key value pair search (lodash or typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, lodash

This is what I want to do:

I have an array of objects which is coming in from our DB. Consider this item: this.usersObj below.

```
@Input() inlinetext: string; <<-- This is the <input> field from the UI
public usersObj: string[]; <<-- This is the usersObj type definition

[
    {
      "fname": "joe",
      "lname": "jones",
      "email: "joe@joe.com"
    },{
      "fname": "pete",
      "lname": "daniels",
      "email: "pete@pete.com"
    },{
      "fname": "peter",
      "lname": "stephens",
      "email: "peter@peter.com"
    },{
      "fname": "mary",
      "lname": "franklin",
      "email: "mary@mary.com"
    },{
      "fname": "jane",
      "lname": "jefferson",
      "email: "jane@jane.com"
    }
]
```

I'm currently using _.forOwn() to grab a specific SUBSET of people based on name search either first name, last name or both.

for this example I'm only searching by first name like so:

```
public getAllUsers(): Observable<Object> {

    let currUserObj: any;
    let allUsersObj: any;

    const endpoint = `${environment.SOCIAL_SHARE.users}/`;

    currUserObj = this._sessionUsersService.getSessionUsers(); // only get current users
    allUsersObj = endpoint;


    console.log('currently logged session users ', currUserObj);
    console.log('all users endpoint: ', allUsersObj);

    this.http.get<Object>(`${endpoint}`, {headers: this.httpheaders}).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.usersObj = response;
        console.log('Get List of Reply Comments Response: ', this.usersObj);
        // Now check for the value inputted with what's in the DB
        this.getUsersOnly();
    }, (error: any) => {
       console.log('Get List of Reply Comments Error: ', error);
    }
  );

  return undefined;
}

public getUsersOnly(): Object {
    // As much as I hate SELF, if we don't use it here, _.forOwn cannot find it
    const self = this;
    // Get all user fnames and lnames ONLY with ID
    // Using Lodash
    let ctr = 0;

    _.forOwn(this.usersObj, function (value: any, key: any) {

    // value is the object
    // console.log('Key Value Pair lodash: ', key + ' : ' + value);

    if (value.firstName !== undefined && value.lastName !== undefined) {
      if (value.firstName === self.inlinetext) {
        for(let i = 0; i < )
        console.log('Found someone: ', key + ' : ' + value.firstName);
        self.retUsers[ctr] += value;
      }
    }
  });
     ctr = 0;
     console.log('Found name object: ', this.retUsers);
     return this.retUsers;
}
```

What I want to achieve is if I type Pete I want to bring back a list of Pete and Peter like so as this.retUsers:

```
[
    {
      "fname": "pete",
      "lname": "daniels",
      "email: "pete@pete.com"
    },{
      "fname": "peter",
      "lname": "stephens",
      "email: "peter@peter.com"
    }
]
```

If I type Peter id only get:

```
[
    {
      "fname": "peter",
      "lname": "stephens",
      "email: "peter@peter.com"
    }
]
```

I'm getting my result back but the resulting object is this...
[image]

The numbers for "Pete" are the "key" of the "values"

What does anyone suggest?

**UPDATE:**

simply use PUSH
**self.retUsers.push(value); <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED TO DO (PUSH)**

**EVEN BETTER UPDATE:**
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9887/how-to-get-started-easily-with-syncfusion-angular-6-multiselect

This does it and removes the need for any of what I did! BOOYAH!

```
_.forOwn(this.usersObj, function (value: any, key: any) {

  // value is the object
  // console.log('Key Value Pair lodash: ', key + ' : ' + value);

  if (value.firstName !== undefined && value.lastName !== undefined) {
    if (value.firstName === self.inlinetext) {
      console.log('Found someone: ', key + ' : ' + value.firstName);
      self.retUsers.push(value); <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED TO DO (PUSH)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please add your own answer instead of adding it to the question.

Answer (score -1):

there are many errors in your code. i would bet that the root cause is that you have `fname` but check the `firstName`. also the code is malformed, and you couldn't really figure out what's exactly wrong.

here's some sketchy example of how to do it:

```
type UserItem = {
  fname?: string;
  lname?: string;
  email?: string;
}

class MyClass {
  public inlineText: string = ''
  public usersObj: UserItem[] = []

  public getUsersOnly(): UserItem[] {
    let txLower = this.inlineText.toLowerCase();

    return this.usersObj.filter(
      ({ fname }) => fname && fname.toLowerCase().startsWith(txLower)
    )
  }
}

const data = new MyClass();
data.usersObj = [
  {
    "fname": "joe",
    "lname": "jones",
    "email": "joe@joe.com"
  }, {
    "fname": "pete",
    "lname": "daniels",
    "email": "pete@pete.com"
  }, {
    "fname": "peter",
    "lname": "stephens",
    "email": "peter@peter.com"
  }, {
    "fname": "mary",
    "lname": "franklin",
    "email": "mary@mary.com"
  }, {
    "fname": "jane",
    "lname": "jefferson",
    "email": "jane@jane.com"
  }
]

data.inlineText = 'Pet'

console.log(data.getUsersOnly())
```

Comment: Leetwinski, trying it out now. Thank you.

Comment: The simple solution is in the UPDATE section.